# Identification of moth in Pandemis heparana trap

Tags: species-identification, entomology

While monitoring *Pandemis heparana* in an apple orchard in **South Tyrol (middle of August)**, I frequently observed huge moths accumulating within the trap. The trap itself is working with pheromones for *Pandemis heparana*.

The moth is 4 cm long and at least 1.5 cm in diameter. It is quite solid and has upper wings which are brownish and lower wings which are bright orange with a distinct black part at the end of the wing.

[image]

Can you help me to identify this moth?

Edit: The moth was dead when i touched it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a group of moths known as the "Underwing moths" for their brilliant coloured hindwings. I think these are used to startle predators when they get too close. They have the brilliant red/orange with a black border. If you could open the wings fully, it would help with ID significantly.

The genus is *[Catocala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catocala)*, which translates to "beautiful lowerone"

For some moths of Austria, you can browse images [here](http://www.entomologia.hu/noctaust/index.php?m=sima), which is how I found the genus name.